# How do I return a subset with a sum closest to the integer 's' when the array does not add up to 's' in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I'm writing a function that takes an integer s and an array of positive integers A and returns an array consisting of elements of A which add up to s.

If there is no subset that adds up to s, the function
should instead return the subset which adds up to the value closest to s.

At the moment my function only returns a subset that adds ups to s.

For example, array A [12, 79, 99, 91, 81, 47], when S is 150 it returns [12,91,47] which adds up to 150.

I'm struggling to get the function to return a subset that adds up to the value closest to s when there is no subset that adds up to s.

For example, for array B [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32], when S is 150 it should return [69,82] which sums to 151 but instead it returns None.

```
def closestSubset(s,A):
        return closestSubsetRec(s,A,len(A))
    
    def closestSubsetRec(s,A,i):
        #s is zero
        if s == 0:
            return []
        #no subset that adds up to s    
        if i == 0 and s!= 0:
            return   
        # else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following 
        # (a) including the last element 
        # (b) excluding the last element    
        withIt = closestSubsetRec(s,A, i-1)  
        withoutIt = closestSubsetRec(s-A[i-1],A,i-1)
         # (b) excluding last element fails
        if withIt == None:
         # (a) including last element fails
            if withoutIt == None:            
                 # (a) including last element successes
                    return 
            else: 
                return append(withoutIt,A[i-1])
        return withIt

A =  [12, 79, 99, 91, 81, 47] 
B = [15, 79, 99, 6, 69, 82, 32]

print(closestSubset(150,A)) 
print(closestSubset(150,B))
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use itertools, or it must be a recursion function only?

Comment: only recursion functions.